# Customize Background in Shopify Section (Dawn Theme)

Tags: css, shopify, liquid

I would like to create three versions of backgrounds that can be set via the section-settings in the Shopify Dawn Theme.

current looks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJWZQ.png

The default theme.liquid defines some global variables:

```css
 --color-base-background-1: 
 {{ settings.colors_background_1.red }}, 
 {{ settings.colors_background_1.green }}, 
 {{ settings.colors_background_1.blue }};
```

This is accessed at various places in the base.css file

Example:

```css
.color-background-1 {
 --color-foreground: var(--color-base-text);
 --color-background: var(--color-base-background-1);
 --gradient-background: var(--gradient-base-background-1); 
}
```

Now I would like to use these global variable also in the respective section.css

```css
.background-none{
  color: var(--color-base-background-1);
  background: green;
 }
```

However this does not produce any results as soon as I use the variable. The color "green" works fine, however the font color does not change as long as I try to use the variable.

Does anyone have an idea how to address this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and found the answer, you can change it directly by clicking on "Customize" in the back office of the store > Theme setings > colors
If you want to create a third option, just copy paste the code of one of the native 2 options, change the name of the variables and add it in base.css, theme.liquid, password.liquid if relevant, and the schemas

Answer (score 0):

the color it's probably being overrided by another class. You can be more specific with your css selectors to override the other class, for example, div.section .background-none.

Additionally, try to create your own new variables --color-base-background and try to understand why you are using var().